# What if GInterface methods signatures don't match with the VirtualTable (struct) methods?

Tags: c, glib, gobject, gio

I decided to go back to basics about GInterfaces in GObject, so I went to read the basic tutorial again. In [this chapter](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/howto-interface.html) you can see how to define a very simple GInterface.

As you can see, the signatures of the methods `maman_ibaz_do_action` and `maman_ibaz_do_something` match, respectively, with the signatures of the symbols `_MamanIbazInterface.do_action` and `_MamanIbazInterface.do_something`.

But what happens if they don't? I have a real-world example. The GInterface is **gpollableinputstream** ([source here](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/master/gio/gpollableinputstream.h)). The method in particular is read_nonblocking() which has 4 parameters in the VT, but later it has 5 parameters in the header function.

So, if an implementor of this interface overrides the former ([real world example here](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/master/gio/gconverterinputstream.c#L604)) how can someone call this implementation from other class?

Comment: clarification needed: are you trying to call the function pointer in the interface directly?

Comment: my intention would be to call the function g_converter_input_stream_read_nonblocking present in line 605 of https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/master/gio/gconverterinputstream.c

Answer (score 0):

The code here is a bit unusual but basically everything works as you would expect it to.

To invoke `g_converter_input_stream_read_nonblocking` you can either

- Invoke it via a `GConverterInputStream` instance's interface pointer:

  ```
  GConverterInputStream *my_gcis;

  ...

  bytes_read =
    G_POLLABLE_INPUT_STREAM_GET_INTERFACE (my_gcis)->
      read_nonblocking (my_gcis, buffer, count, error);
  ```

  or
- Invoke it via the interface method, `g_pollable_input_stream_read_nonblocking`, which adds a fifth parameter and some extra functionality:

  ```
  bytes_read =
    g_pollable_input_stream_read_nonblocking (G_POLLABLE_INPUT_STREAM (my_gcis),
                                              buffer,
                                              count,
                                              cancellable,
                                              error);
  ```

The second approach works because *internally* `g_pollable_input_stream_read_nonblocking` calls the normal, "four-parameter" version of the function, as defined by the interface, at [gpollableinputstream.c:212](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/master/gio/gpollableinputstream.c#L212):

```
res = G_POLLABLE_INPUT_STREAM_GET_INTERFACE (stream)->
  read_nonblocking (stream, buffer, count, error);
```

It's unusual for an interface's method to provide more functionality than simply this, but aside from that everything here works as it normally does.